# Get client's date format name

Tags: javascript, c#, date-format

I have an MVC website (in C#) on a windows server in USA.

I have a client in Israel (for example) that enters the website.

The date format name in Israel is "he-IL" and the string format is "dd/MM/yyyy" (day before month), but the client's browser is in english, not hebrew.

I want that when the client enters the website - the javascript will know (using JS functions or by information from the server) what's the client date format name [he-IL], or at least date format string [dd/MM/yyyy].

Is it possible?

Comment: Javascript has no access to the user's desired date format or component order. You can attempt to guess it using *Date.prototype.toLocaleString*, but that is entirely browser dependent and utterly unreliable. Best to use an unambiguous format such as ISO 8601 or words for the month (e.g. 23-Feb-2014 or similar).

Answer (score 1):

Usually the regional settings of the browser would allow you to retrieve this information. If your client set his browser settings in English, it means that he wants to use English format for the dates. Why would you want to go against his will?

If you want to go against his will, the only way to achieve that is to use some geolocating service which will attempt to locate the country from the IP address and then based on this country format the dates as you wish.

Comment: I'm from Israel - most of the developers here prefer to use browsers in English (sometime the translate to Hebrew isn't good enough and other reasons) but we really don't want to see dates in English formats because it's confusing.